# Hadoop/Hive : Loading data from .csv on a remote machine

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am having a csv file that can from a http url. Is there any way I can load it from there :-

This is what I am trying

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'http://192.168.56.101:8081/TeamHalf.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE csvdata;
```

Comment: what's the issue ? is there a error msg that you are getting ?

Comment: No actually I am trying to copy file from a http server. But it is not possible. I am trying to import result set of mysql db to hive both on different server and filesystem. This works for me using sqoop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400513/how-to-run-a-sqoop-import-from-a-hive-thrift-client-to-a-hive-thrift-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive Load command is a follows :

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

1) if LOCAL specified - Loads from local FS filepath

2) if no LOCAL - Loads from HDFS filepath only i.e,:
     filepath must refer to files within the same filesystem as the table's (or partition's) location

So Load from remote http:path won't work. refer [HIVE DML](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML) . The possible way is (Staging) to load the data from remote http:path to LocalFS or HDFS , then to Hive Warehouse.

Comment: I think this the correct answer but unfortunately not the solution for my issue. Still thanks I got my problem solved using sqoop.